# more command - linux

Tags: linux, terminal, command

When I use the command more with || or with && it look like it always return true.

```
~/Desktop$ more notExists || echo aaa
notExists: No such file or directory
~/Desktop$ more notExists && echo aaa
notExists: No such file or directory
aaa
```

I want understand why is it happened,Can someone explain to me?

(If this is not the right place for this question feel free to pass).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More seems to be misbehaving indeed ('less' does not have that issue, and

```
less notExist || echo "failed"
```

works as you would expect.

Try with an explicit test:

```
 if test -f $file; then more $file; else echo "failed"; fi
```

Comment: On the linux machine I tested (and OSX), 'more notExist && echo aa' will indeed output aa. That's because more always seems to have an exist status of 0, even when the file is not found

Comment: On my system, the manual page for `more` does not state anything about exit codes, so it's entirely possible it's not "misbehaving" at all - it may be behaving exactly as designed, but just isn't designed the way one might expect...